Making gap in ul elemets
how to make so my three elements are strecthed out evenly?
I want to be like this
This is me, coding


.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.js-spacebetween {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
<footer class="padding-footer">
      <div class="wrapper-80 flex js-spacebetween">
        <div class="left">
          <img src="./images/Vector (3).png" alt="white logo" />
          <p>International Foundation for Electoral Systems (IFES)</p>
          <div class="flex">
            <p><i class="fa-solid fa-phone"></i>+389-2-312-2288</p>
            <p><i class="fa-regular fa-envelope"></i>ifes.nmk@ifes.org</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
          <ul>
            <a href="#">Информирај се</a>
            <a href="#">Дискусии</a>
            <a href="#">Контакт - корисни линкови</a>
            <a href="#">Закон за заштита на личните податоци</a>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <ul>
            <li>MK | AL</li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-square-facebook"></i></a>
              <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i></a>
              <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-youtube"></i></a>
              <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-tiktok"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li>© All Rights Reserved. | safeblink.mk</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>



Don't bother by the styling, all i want is the design to be like the picture

Your HTML is invalid. An anchor is not a valid child of a list. I strongly suggest that you use a good editor or an HTML validator.

What you need to do is add an additional rule to the css, give all 3 div a width of 100% and they'll take up even width.


.left, .center, .right {
    width: 100%;
}



You can then go into each div and flex  again to your design requirement but the above makes sure they all take up equal width.
